# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans

I am trying to set up a JDBC driver and connection to a database in NetBeans. In the new connection wizard I have filled out the following info:

[image: Netbeans New Connection Wizard]

I keep getting the error

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

I am following the steps on https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html precisely and it is still not allowing me to do this? Why is this so complicated in NetBeans?

Any help would be appreciated. I have confirmed that the server is running on my local PC with URL: 127.0.0.1

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: do you mean the jdbc driver? it is ojdbc7

Comment: Lol... ok my bad. I am trying to install a ojdbc.jar for a mysql server. My bad. This question may be closed

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any Help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Following things

1. Do u have Oracle at your local machine, if not change the Host to
   appropriate value.
2. Check if you fire wall is allowing Both oracle and neat bean to
   access these ports.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your listener port is running with

```
lsnrctl status
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your oracle is running at port you are about to specify in Netbeans.